# Couldn't migrate to another service version with GCloud CLI

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, command-line-interface, gcloud

I have read the document which says that `gcloud app versions migrate` operation can migrate traffics into another version, but it couldn't. The error description seems to say something informative, but no help to me. On GCP control panel, version migration works fine. What's happening on this?

```
 $ gcloud app versions migrate 20190122-120543-ebbfbc9 -s q
 Migrating all traffic from version [q/20190129-164614-09e8288] to 
 [q/20190122-120543-ebbfbc9]
 Do you want to continue (Y/n)?

 ERROR: (gcloud.app.versions.migrate) Issues migrating all traffic of service(s): [q]

 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Invalid request.
 - '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest
   fieldViolations:
   - description: Warmup requests must be enabled for all versions that will gain additional
       traffic as a result of the traffic migration.
     field: service.split.allocations[20190122-120543-ebbfbc9]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `gcloud app versions migrate` it will try to do a [gradual migration](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/migrating-traffic#migrating_traffic_gradually). Gradual traffic migration is only supported for the Standard environment and you have to enable [warmup requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/configuring-warmup-requests) on the target version for this to work.

It’s working on GCP Console because there you’ll be prompted to do an immediate migration if the above conditions are not met.

If you want to use gcloud to migrate traffic to a GAE Standard version set to warmup disabled, or Flex environment, you can use the following command which will actually split the traffic immediately (not gradually) 100% to the target version:

`gcloud app services set-traffic [MY_SERVICE] --splits [MY_VERSION]=1`

You can find more information [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/migrating-traffic#migrating_traffic_to_a_new_version)

Hope it helps! :)